# toString function from 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, tostring

**Very sorry if this is too long**--  I posted a question yesterday about a game program I am trying to write and with the help of some people, I managed to figure everything out pretty quickly.

The very large majority of the program is complete, but I have one last weird task to complete. I have a function written, printGrid, that prints one random element from each 16 bundles of characters from within a char array. For example (It's very ugly-- please excuse my beginner code):

```
        char gameZero[outer_size][inner_size] = {
    {'A','A','C','I','O','T'}, {'A','H','M','O','R','S'},  

    {'E','G','K','L','U','Y'}, {'A','B','I','L','T','Y'}, {'A','C','D','E','M','P'},   
     {'E','G','I','N','T','V'}, {'G','I','L','R','U','W'}, {'E','L','P','S','T','U'},  
     {'D','E','N','O','S','W'}, {'A','C','E','L','R','S'}, {'A','B','J','M','O','Q'},  
     {'E','E','F','H','I','Y'}, {'E','H','I','N','P','S'}, {'D','K','N','O','T','U'},  
 {'A','D','E','N','V','Z'}, {'B','I','F','O','R','X'}  
     };  
    void printGrid() {
mt19937 gen(time(nullptr));
uniform_int_distribution<int> random_inner(0, inner_size - 1);
int n = random_inner(gen);

cout << "+---+---+---+---+\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << "| " << gameZero[i][n] << " ";
cout << "\n+---+---+---+---+\n";
for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    cout << "| " << gameZero[i][n] << " ";
cout << "\n+---+---+---+---+\n";
for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++)
    cout << "| " << gameZero[i][n] << " ";
cout << "\n+---+---+---+---+\n";
for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++)
    cout << "| " << gameZero[i][n] << " ";
cout << "\n+---+---+---+---+\n";

}
```

This will print a 4x4 game board for the user to see. I am now trying to write a sort of toString function, which takes the random numbers generated in printGrid and prints them out into a single line string with no spaces. The issue I am trying to wrap my head around is, I have this assortment of characters that changes each time the player begins a new game. These 16 characters are coming from a set array of 16 die, holding 6 characters each. Is the only way to make this possible to store these new randomly chosen characters into an empty array so the user can simply print them with the toString function when desired? Another obstacle I would have to then tackle is deleting the array every time the user wants to begin again. If this is the case, could I store them in a vector and use something like vector::clear to solve that?

Current output of printGrid function:

```
 +---+---+---+---+
 | T | M | E | L |
 +---+---+---+---+
 | A | V | L | S |
 +---+---+---+---+
 | E | A | Qu| F |
 +---+---+---+---+
 | E | D | N | O |
 +---+---+---+---+
```

Desired output of toString function I would like to create:

```
 TMELAVLSEAQuFEDNO
```

Very sorry if this is too much to read or too confusing- I've been working on this almost all day and my brain is a bit fried at the moment. Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your post with the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews done, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand.  You have the logic to select characters when you draw the grid.  You may want to use the same logic but use `std::string` and the operator `+=` to append the selected characters to the string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are 100% right. I've been trying to wrap my head around the entire project all day that I seem to get easily lost in the simple things. I've added a vector and push_back statements in the for loop and simply printed out the elements in the vector. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic to select the characters, example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << "| " << gameZero[i][n] << " ";
```

You could use `std::string` and operator `+=` to append the characters to a string:
std::string all_letters;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
  all_letters += gameZero[i][n];
}
```

**Edit 1: Expanding the loop**
Since you don't need to print by row, you can iterate through the entire array:

```
std::string all_letters;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    all_letters += gameZero[i][n];
}
```